# Issues with the website hosted on EC2

Tags: tomcat, joomla, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have hosted a website on EC2, it is running on apache tomcat server. Recently, the traffic on my website is increased and again and again I am getting the following error when I am trying to access my website:

```
The webpage is currently unavailable. It may be overloaded or down 
for maintenance.
```

Following is my instance details:

1. RAM = 1.7 GB
2. Disk space = 100 GB

Following is output of free -m (RAM details):

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          3750       1566       2184          0        172        639
-/+ buffers/cache:        754       2996
Swap:         7167          0       7167
```

The status of my instance is: 2/2 checks passed. I am unable to figure out what is wrong with my website.

Sometimes, it is working fine but sometimes I get this error. Can anyone tell me what is wrong?

Comment: Not enough information provided as to your environment and instance sizes.

Comment: @datasage Added some more information, please have a look. Let me know if more information to be added

Comment: Sounds like it is `m1.medium` instance. Have you thought of upgrading the instance to `m1.large`? It will provide more compute power. Also, AWS provides better network throughput when you go for higher instance sizes.

Comment: 1.7 GB is at m1.small, m1.medium has 3.5 GB. are you running behind an elb?

Comment: @andreimarinescu Yes, it is behind an ELB

Comment: AWS ELB's don't scale very well at traffic spikes. If you're seeing spikes of more than 50% over 5 mins, and your CPU isn't maxed out, and your Apache MaxClients limit isn't maxed out, most probably it's the ELB (http://aws.amazon.com/articles/1636185810492479)

Comment: @andreimarinescu Yes ELB is the problem, what should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I copied the text from my comment (AWS ELB's don't scale very well at traffic spikes. If you're seeing spikes of more than 50% over 5 mins, and your CPU isn't maxed out, and your Apache MaxClients limit isn't maxed out, most probably it's the ELB).

In case the ELB is the issue, you have several options:

- if you have access to AWS support, you can schedule a prewarming of the ELB, so that it is not under capacity when traffic spikes.
- if not, you can prewarm the ELB yourself using a simple script such as siege or apache ab, gradually increasing traffic up to the limit you need. Don't add more than 50% traffic every 5 minutes.
- if you have a CNAME record pointing to the ELB hostname, make sure the TTL set on the record is 60 seconds. The way ELB scales is that they change the DNS record to larger and larger instances. If you have a high TTL on your own CNAME record, you'll be directing traffic to the old and underpowered instance.
- you can alternatively switch to your own load balancing solution. We have done this in the past as we face very unpredictable and spikey traffic. I highly recommend HAProxy, as it's quite easy to configure and very reliable. The downside is that you'll have to scale it yourself and it will cost more than the 20 USD / month that ELB costs.

Comment: Can you tell me how to check the CNAME associated with the elb plzzzz

Comment: Well, how are you accessing the ELB? Don't you have a DNS record for it?

Comment: If this solved your issue, please accept the answer so that other users might consider this useful too.

Comment: Thanks man, the problem was that the ELB was down tooked help from AWS support and resolved it.